# How to create draggable components with javascript and react hooks?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, draggable

I need to add draggable divs, one for every image in an array of images, to a container.

The below works BUT only on the second drag. i.e. I have to drag the component twice for it to move. It obviously has something to do with the hooks used and how the divs are being created. Any help will be appreciated.

[Code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-wing-3vdd3y)

```
const App = ({images}) => {
  const [selectedImages, setSelectedImages] = useState(images)
  const [dragId, setDragId] = useState()

  const handleDrag = (ev) => {
    setDragId(ev.currentTarget.id)
  }

  const handleDrop = (ev) => {
    const sortedImages = sortImages(selectedImages, dragId)
    setSelectedImages(sortedImages)
  }

  return (
    <Container
      images={selectedImages}
      handleDrag={handleDrag}
      handleDrop={handleDrop}
    />
  )
}

export default App

const Container = ({ images, handleDrag, handleDrop }) => {
  const ref = useRef(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    if (containerRef.current) {

      for (let i = 0; i < images.length; ++i) {
        const draggable = document.createElement('div')
        draggable.ondragstart = handleDrag
        draggable.ondrop = handleDrop

        const style = 'position: absolute; ...'

        draggable.setAttribute('style', style)
        draggable.setAttribute('draggable', true)
        draggable.setAttribute('id', images[i].id)

        ref.current.appendChild(draggable)
      }
    }
  }, [images, ref, handleDrag, handleDrop])


  return (
    <div className={'relative'}>
      <div ref={ref} />
    </div>
  )
}

export default Container
```

It looks like it is setting the dragId on first drag and then only on the second drag it actually drags and drops the div. How can I set this up so that it drags and drops on the first try?

Comment: please provide the sandbox code with url. Then easy to work with the problem that you mentioning

Comment: I added sandbox example

Comment: I wonder why you use this native js append logic in the useEffect Hook? Why don't you generate the markup using react?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I should have just used React to add the functions

```
const Container = ({ images, handleDrag, handleDrop }) => {
  const containerRef = useRef(null)
  
  return (
    <div ref={containerRef}>
      {images.map((image) => (
        <div
          key={image.id}
          id={image.id}
          draggable
          onDragOver={(ev) => ev.preventDefault()}
          onDrop={handleDrop}
          onDragStart={handleDrag}
          style={{
            position: 'absolute'...`,
          }}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  )
}

export default Container
```

[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-lamarr-tn9q7s?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: can you share the answer with the sandbox URL? Because I need to play with the code.

Comment: For complex and many deeply nested/complicated drag and drop logic you can take a look at `react-dnd` [docs](https://react-dnd.github.io/react-dnd/)